# How do I save an object for use later? Send via JSON or othewise and store in DB then recover

Tags: javascript, jquery, save

I would love to figure out how to save a `event.target` for later use.  I realize `.data()` can be used but that wouldn't save it across session or for a different user.

I find that I can get a bunch of information about an element (class, id, parents, etc) that was clicked if I do something like this...

```
jQuery('body').click( function(event) {
    jQuery('body').children().wrapAll('<div class="wp_super_heatmap"></div');

    x_coord = event.pageX - jQuery( event.target ).offset().left;
    y_coord = event.pageY - jQuery( event.target ).offset().top;


    nodeName = event.target.nodeName;
    nodeClass = event.target.className;
    currentId = jQuery(event.target).attr('id');
    nodeParents = jQuery(event.target).parents()
        .map(function () { 
              return this.tagName; 
        }).get().join(", ");
```

but, what I REALLY want to do is do something like....

```
node = jQuery( event.target );
node_json = JSON.stringify( node );
```

and then send it off with my AJAX post.

Basically, does anyone know of a way to save javascript or jQuery objects for later use?

---

EDIT: FYI, later I am recreating the click by placing a dot on a page like this...
    jQuery.each(data.dot_collection, function() { 
    x_coord = this.x_coord;
    y_coord = this.y_coord;
    jQuery('').css({'top': y_coord + "px", 'left': x_coord + "px"}).appendTo('body');
    });

Comment: You cannot serialize DOM elements (easily) because they contain circular references. First you have to identify *which* data you need. So what is it exactly?

Comment: Well, that is the thing.  I want to save exactly where a user clicks on a webpage.  Since items can float around or be centered on the page or whatever I would like to be able to save the relative coordinates of the click and the enough information about that click to put a 'dot' there later.  My issue is that the class, type, id, etc doesn't really give enough information about the clicked element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Ryan, DOM nodes are not easy to serialize. For more sophisticated apps you should rely on better patterns and add a model layer to your application. Just track user input in a object tree in javascript and add eventhandlers that set these values accordingly.

These objects can than be serialized on unload and deserialized onload. A nice benfit is that you app will look much cleaner and is better to maintain.

I mean something like [this](http://benpickles.github.com/js-model/), but be aware that such functionality is as easy self implemented.

If you like you can even use local storage with a (non trivial) script like [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).

**UPDATE**

I know this sounds like a lot of work, but trust me decisions like these always pay of!

Comment: I see.  What I am getting from that is that it would be a good idea to create a model that has a node tree like -> html -> body -> etc and then add eventhandlers that add a 'dot' in the model that is referenced to one of those objects in the tree.  Is that sort of what you meant?

Comment: I don't mind the work.  It keeps me busy and working on my webdev hobby =).

Comment: I don't mean it in a big way, I mean it in a small way ;). Take some time and decide what structure it should have. Most of the time a tree is not even necessary. I certainly would not copy the whole DOM, just add some data to a Hash and use sync this.

Comment: I am not sure how I would be able to identify which element was clicked without having the whole DOM tree. You lost me on "just add some data to a Hash and use sync this."  If that is a way to actually save the data I am goo on that side.  This all runs on WordPress so I have easy access to the DB.

Comment: I would just have one object that laid out the structure of the DOM.  Separate 'dot' objects would reference which element in the DOM.  Obviously, if you changed the DOM old 'dots' would no longer be valid.

Comment: @Ryan: One possibility could be to get a XPath expression for that element.

Comment: I never even knew XPath existed! Haha, thanks.  That looks extremely promising from a quick google.

Comment: All Elements can be moved? Is this a editor of some sort? In this case you would need to implement a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) of some sort as a model.

Comment: Well, they can move and float.  Say, for one example, that you had a single DIV that had `margin:0 auto` and was floating in the middle of the browser.  If you changed the width of the browser and clicked in the middle of the page before and after your x/y coordinates would be different.  But, you clicked in the same 'spot'.  If there is a better way to go about doing this I am all eyes.  What I am trying to do is create a heatmap just for fun.  But, I am trying to keep it general to work on ANY webpage with no a priori knowledge.

Comment: Oh my, I just saw jQuery natively supports XPath too.  Thanks Floyd and Felix!! I definitely would have stumbled around and never found that.

Comment: It looks like jQuery doesn't actually support XPath natively since 1.2.  Just in case anyone else stumbles on this thread.  This may be of use...http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2#XPath_Compatibility_Plugin

Comment: I am dumb...instead of using XPath, just use a standard jQuery selector.  You end up with the same result.